# outtring initated in BluetoothcommandService.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth, arduino

I, will be asking how to combine/fuse 2 java files if,the outstring was initiated in the BluetoothcommandService.java file I will be editing my Post sir and post my MainActivity.java file and BluetoothCommandService.java file..I just doent know how to combine it..

this is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    BluetoothAdapter            BTAdapter;
    BluetoothDevice             BTDevice;


    private TextView title;
    private static final int    REQUEST_DEVICE_CONNECT = 1;
    private static final int    REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 2;


    private BluetoothCommandService commandService = null;

    private String connectedDeviceName = null;

    //Message types sent from the Handler
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
    public static final int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 6;



    //Will be used in BluetoothCommandSrvice jave file
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";
    public static final String DEVICENAME = "device name";


    //@@@@@@@for the controller
    public static final String tagStateCTRL = "Controller";
    private OutputStream outStream = null;
    private static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static String address = "00:00:00:00:00:00"; // Insert your bluetooth devices MAC address
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Button btn_d1_on, btn_d1_off;

    //for changing the device_1 name
    TextView device1;
    Button change;
    EditText renameDevice;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); gi move sa ubos sa request window

        // Set up the window layout
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
            title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_left_text);  // Set up the custom title
            title.setText(R.string.app_name);                       // Set up the custom title
            title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_right_text); // Set up the custom title

        //Button openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open);

        //@@@@@@@@@@for the controller    
        btn_d1_on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.device1_on);
        btn_d1_off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.device1_off);

        //@@@@@@@@for changing the device_1 name
        device1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.device1);
        change = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTest);
        renameDevice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTest);
        change.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String change_device1 = renameDevice.getText().toString();
                device1.setText(change_device1);
            }
        });


        // AUTO REQUEST OF ENABLING THE BLUETOOTH
        BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        //A code that will detect if BT is enabled otherwise will require it.
        if (BTAdapter == null)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(context, text, duration)
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Bluetooth adapter is available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        } 

        //@@@@@@@@@@for the controller
        btn_d1_on.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //sendData("1");
                //Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The device is now On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                //msg.show()
                btn_d1_on.setEnabled(false);
                sendData("1");      
            }
        });

        //@@@@@@@@@@for the controller
        btn_d1_off.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //sendData("0");
                //Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The device is now On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                //msg.show();
                btn_d1_off.setEnabled(false);
                sendData("0");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Requesting Bluetooth automatically when its not yet enabled.
        if (!BTAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            //startActivityForResult(enableIntent, 0);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
        }
        else
        {
            if (commandService == null)
                setupCommand();
        }
    }



        //if (BTAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE)
        //{
            //Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            //discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 500);
            //startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        //}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (commandService != null)
        {
            if (commandService.getState() == BluetoothCommandService.stateNothing)
            {
                commandService.start();
            }
        }       
    }

    private void setupCommand()
    {
        commandService = new BluetoothCommandService(this, bluetoothHandler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (commandService != null)
            commandService.stop();
    }

    private void ensureDiscoverable()
    {
        //Get the current Bluetooth scan mode of the local Bluetooth adapter. The Bluetooth scan mode determines if the local adapter is connectable and/or discoverable from remote Bluetooth devices. 
        if (BTAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE)
        {
            Intent ensureDiscoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            ensureDiscoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(ensureDiscoverableIntent);
        }
    }

    //This gets information back from the "BluetoothChatService"/"BluetoothCommandService"
    //@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    //private final Handler bluetoothHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback()
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    public final Handler bluetoothHandler = new Handler()
    {   
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)
        {
            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1)
                    {
                        case BluetoothCommandService.stateConnected:
                            title.setText(R.string.title_connectedTo);
                            title.append(connectedDeviceName);
                            break;

                        case BluetoothCommandService.stateConnecting:
                            title.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                            break;

                        case BluetoothCommandService.stateListen:
                        case BluetoothCommandService.stateNothing:
                            title.setText(getString(R.string.title_notConnected));
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                    connectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICENAME);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to " + connectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive message
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                    sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // if end-of-line,
                        //String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);             // extract string
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                        //txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint);          // update TextView
                        //1/4/14
                        btn_d1_on.setEnabled(true);
                        btn_d1_off.setEnabled(true); 
                    }
                    //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                    break;

            }
            //return false;
        }
    };
    //});

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_DEVICE_CONNECT:
            // When DeviceList Activity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the device MAC address
                String address = data.getExtras()
                                     .getString(DeviceList.EXTRA_DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS);
                // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
                BluetoothDevice device = BTAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                // Attempt to connect to the device
                commandService.connect(device);
            }
            break;

        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                setupCommand();
            } else {
               // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.notEnabledBluetooth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
           }


        }
    }


    @Override
    //Creating an Option Menu for connectivity and discoverability of a BT device
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        //MenuInflater is a class
        MenuInflater OptionMenu = getMenuInflater();
        //OptionMenu.inflate(menuRes, menu)
        OptionMenu.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.connect:
                Intent serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceList.class);
                //this.startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_DEVICE_CONNECT);
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_DEVICE_CONNECT);
                return true;
            case R.id.discoverable:
                ensureDiscoverable();
                return true;
            //case R.id.abouts:
                //Intent intentabouts = new Intent(this,abouts.class);
                //return true;
            //default:
                //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
        {
            commandService.write(BluetoothCommandService.VOL_UP);
            return true;
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
        {
            commandService.write(BluetoothCommandService.VOL_DOWN);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
      private void sendData(String message)
      //public void sendData(String message)
      {
          byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

          Log.d(tagStateCTRL, "...Sending data: " + message + "...");

          try {
              outStream.write(msgBuffer);
          }
          catch (IOException e){
              String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
              if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00")) 
                  msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address in the java code";
              msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + myUUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

          errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);       
        }
      }

      private void errorExit(String title, String message){
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            msg.show();
            finish();
          }
    //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
}
```

This is the BluetoothCommanService.java

public class BluetoothCommandService {

```
private final BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter;
private final Handler bluetoothHandler;
private int connectionState;
private ConnectThread connectThread;
//private ConnectedThread connectedThread;
public ConnectedThread connectedThread;
//***Added 12/27/13
private AcceptThread mainAcceptThread;

//connection states of the Bluetooth
public static final int stateNothing = 0; //doing nothing
public static final int stateListen = 1; //listening for incoming connections
public static final int stateConnecting = 2; //initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int stateConnected = 3;

//constants that indicate command to computer
public static final int exitCMD = -1;
public static final int VOL_UP = 1;
public static final int VOL_DOWN = 2;

private static final boolean D = true;
private static final String tagState = "BluetoothCommandService";

//universally unique identifier (UUID)
//The intent of UUIDs is to enable distributed systems to uniquely identify information without significant central coordination
//private static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("04c6093b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
 private static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");

//Name for the SDP (don;t know what is it) record when creating server socket
private static final String name = "BluetoothCommand";

public BluetoothCommandService(Context context, Handler handler) { // context == UI Activity Context && handler == send message back to the UI Activity
    BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    connectionState = stateNothing;
    bluetoothHandler = handler;
}

private  synchronized void setState(int state) { // state == current connection state; an integer
    if (D) Log.d(tagState, "setState() " + connectionState + " -> " + state);
    connectionState = state;

    //Give the new state to the Handler so that the UI Activity can update
    //bluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(what, arg1, arg2)
    bluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();        
}

public synchronized int getState() { //return the current connection state
    return connectionState;
}

public synchronized void start() {
    if (D) Log.d(tagState, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (connectThread != null) 
    {
        connectThread.cancel();
        connectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (connectedThread != null)
    {
        connectedThread.cancel();
        connectedThread = null;
    }

     // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
    if (mainAcceptThread == null) 
    {
        mainAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        mainAcceptThread.start();
    }

    setState(stateListen);
}

//device == the BluetoothDevice to connect
public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (D) Log.d(tagState, "connect to: " + device);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (connectionState == stateConnecting) {
        if (connectThread != null)
        {
            connectThread.cancel(); 
            connectThread = null;
        }
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (connectedThread != null) 
    {
        connectedThread.cancel(); 
        connectedThread = null;
    }

 // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
    if (mainAcceptThread != null) 
    {
        mainAcceptThread.cancel(); 
        mainAcceptThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    connectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    connectThread.start();
    setState(stateConnecting);
}

public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (D) Log.d(tagState, "connected");

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (connectThread != null) 
    {
        connectThread.cancel(); 
        connectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (connectedThread != null) 
    {
        connectedThread.cancel(); 
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    if (mainAcceptThread != null) 
    {
        mainAcceptThread.cancel(); 
        mainAcceptThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    connectedThread.start();


    Message msg = bluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(MainActivity.DEVICENAME, device.getName());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    bluetoothHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    setState(stateConnected);
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    if (D) Log.d(tagState, "stop");

    if (connectThread != null) 
    {
        connectThread.cancel(); 
        connectThread = null;
    }

    if (connectedThread != null) 
    {
        connectedThread.cancel(); 
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    if (mainAcceptThread != null) 
    {
        mainAcceptThread.cancel(); 
        mainAcceptThread = null;
    }

    setState(stateNothing);
}

public void write(byte[] out) {

    ConnectedThread r;

    synchronized (this) {
        if (connectionState != stateConnected) return;
        r = connectedThread;
    }
    r.write(out);
}

public void write(int out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (connectionState != stateConnected) return;
        r = connectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}

private void connectionFailed() {
    setState(stateListen);

    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = bluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(MainActivity.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    bluetoothHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionLost() {
        setState(stateListen);
        Message msg = bluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        bluetoothHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}


private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket connectThread_socket;
    private final BluetoothDevice connectThread_device;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        connectThread_device = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        //Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection w/ the given BT device
        //try {


        //catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e(tag, msg, tr)
            //Log.e(tagState, "create() failed", e);}

        //Added 12/28/13
        Method m;
        try {
                m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);

        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } 


        connectThread_socket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(tagState, "BEGIN ConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");

       BTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
           connectThread_socket.connect();}
            catch (IOException e) {
                connectionFailed();
                try {
                    connectThread_socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(tagState, "Unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }

                BluetoothCommandService.this.start();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothCommandService.this) {
                connectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(connectThread_socket, connectThread_device); //ERROR: will still create "connected"
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                connectThread_socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }

    }
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket connectedThread_socket;
        private final InputStream connectedThread_inStream;
        private final OutputStream connectedThread_outStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(tagState, "create ConnectedThread");
            connectedThread_socket = socket;

            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

         // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            connectedThread_inStream = tmpIn;
            connectedThread_outStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(tagState, "BEGIN ConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // WALA JUD KO KASABOT ANI MAN :D

          while (true) {
                try {
                    int bytes = connectedThread_inStream.read(buffer);
                   bluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer) 
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(tagState, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost(); //ERROR: will still create "private void CONNECTIONLOST"
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                connectedThread_outStream.write(buffer);

                  } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void write(int out) {
            try {
                connectedThread_outStream.write(out);
         } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                connectedThread_outStream.write(exitCMD);
                connectedThread_socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket acceptThread_ServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                tmp = BTAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, myUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "listen() failed", e);
            }
            acceptThread_ServerSocket = tmp;
        }
        public void run() {
            if (D) Log.d(tagState, "BEGIN mainAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread");
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            while (connectionState != stateConnected) {
                try {

                    socket = acceptThread_ServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(tagState, "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }


                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothCommandService.this) {
                        switch (connectionState) {
                        case stateListen:
                        case stateConnecting:

                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case stateNothing:
                        case stateConnected:

                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(tagState, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D) Log.i(tagState, "END mainAcceptThread");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D) Log.d(tagState, "cancel " + this);
            try {
                acceptThread_ServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(tagState, "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post `MainActivity` code and indicate line 377

Comment: this is my line 377

try {
     outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
     String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
     if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00")) 
      msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address in the java code";
     msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + myUUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";
       
       errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);       
     }

Comment: @post full code by editing your post

Comment: Thanks for helping ,the full codes are here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920327/error-on-sending-string-value-0off-and-1on-to-arduino-via-bluetooth-in-a

Comment: `outStream` is null not initialized. Why din't you wait for some to answer on that post.

Comment: sorry sir,but no one answers and found hopeful.
Sir I, will be asking how to combine/fuse 2 java files if,the outstring was initieated in the BluetoothcommandService.java file
I will be editing my Post sir and post my MainActivity.java file and BluetoothCommandService.java file..I just doent know how to combine it sir..

Comment: for clearer codes 
this is my mainactivity http://www.mediafire.com/view/nd32ae5jcaf46at/MainActivity%20extends%20Activity.pdf
and this is the BluetoothCommandService
http://www.mediafire.com/view/xg667yx8mfllf3a/BluetoothCommandService.pdf
please help me sir.. I'm begging .. :'(